# There is a way to align table captions to the left in "longtblr" environment?

Tags: latex

When using the caption package with the option "singleline check = off," the caption in a "table"+"tblr" environment seems to align left with no problem. In contrast, this option didn't affect when using "longtblr" environment.

I have tried using "table"+"longtble" environments together, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to align table captions to the left in a "longtblr" environment? Any suggestion is appreciable. Thank you for your advice.

[image]

Here is the sample.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{This is a normal table caption}
\begin{tblr}{
    width=1\linewidth,
    colspec={XXX},
    hlines, vlines
    }
Head & Head & Head \\
Head & Data & Data \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption={This is a long-table caption that should align left}
    ]{
    width=1\linewidth,
    colspec={XXX},
    hlines, vlines,
    rowhead=1
    }
Head & Head & Head \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

This is doesn't work

```
\begin{table}
    \caption{This is doesn't work}
\begin{longtblr}{
    width=1\linewidth,
    colspec={XXX},
    hlines, vlines,
    rowhead=1
    }
Head & Head & Head \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{table}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you re-evaluate your choice of accepted answer, now that there is a much better one by @Celdor ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did try the solution from @Celdor and it also worked. This solution gives me some clues to investigate more about modifying the tabularray template.

Comment: I did evaluate your suggestion compared to @Celdor's suggestion. Your suggestion worked best when combined with the caption package `captionsetup[table]format=hang`. If the table captions were long enough, the text had to hang on the next line. @Celdor's advice may align the table caption to the left, but the caption did not hang even after the caption package was set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the TblrTemplates like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DefTblrTemplate { caption } { normal }
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__tblr_caption_box
      {
        \UseTblrTemplate { caption-tag } { default }
        \UseTblrTemplate { caption-sep } { default }
        \UseTblrTemplate { caption-text } { default }
      }
    \dim_compare:nNnTF { \box_wd:N \l__tblr_caption_box } > { \hsize }
      {
        \UseTblrAlign { caption }
        \UseTblrIndent { caption }
        \hbox_set:Nn \l__tblr_caption_left_box
          {
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-tag } { default }
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-sep } { default }
          }
        \hangindent = \box_wd:N \l__tblr_caption_left_box
        \hangafter = 1
        \UseTblrHang { caption }
        \leavevmode
        \hbox_unpack:N \l__tblr_caption_box
        \par
      }
      {
        \centering
        \makebox [\hsize] [l] { \box_use:N \l__tblr_caption_box }
        \par
      }
  }
  
\DefTblrTemplate { capcont } { normal }
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__tblr_caption_box
      {
        \UseTblrTemplate { caption-tag } { default }
        \UseTblrTemplate { caption-sep } { default }
        \UseTblrTemplate { caption-text } { default }
        \space
        \UseTblrTemplate { conthead-text } { default }
      }
    \dim_compare:nNnTF { \box_wd:N \l__tblr_caption_box } > { \hsize }
      {
        \UseTblrAlign { capcont }
        \UseTblrIndent { capcont }
        \hbox_set:Nn \l__tblr_caption_left_box
          {
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-tag } { default }
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-sep } { default }
          }
        \hangindent = \box_wd:N \l__tblr_caption_left_box
        \hangafter = 1
        \UseTblrHang { capcont }
        \leavevmode
        \hbox_unpack:N \l__tblr_caption_box
        \par
      }
      {
        \centering
        \makebox [\hsize] [l] { \box_use:N \l__tblr_caption_box }
        \par
      }
  }  
  
\SetTblrTemplate{caption}{normal}
\SetTblrTemplate{capcont}{normal}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{This is a normal table caption}
\begin{tblr}{
    width=1\linewidth,
    colspec={XXX},
    hlines, vlines
    }
Head & Head & Head \\
Head & Data & Data \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}


\begin{longtblr}[
    caption={This is a long-table caption that should align left}
    ]{
    width=1\linewidth,
    colspec={XXX},
    hlines, vlines,
    rowhead=1
    }
Head & Head & Head \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution regarding `longtblr` is to add the following to your preamble

```
\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{%
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}%
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}%
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}%
}
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{%
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}%
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}%
  \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}%
}
```

but this affects all `longtblr` tables.

The `tabularray` has its own way to format parts of its tables. Particularly, `longtblr` operates on templates, which in turn can be applied to styles. If you want your tables to have different themes, you will need to defined custom templates and styles with custom themes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and advice. This also works like the solution from @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. I'll look into the Tabularray theme and style further.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the suggestions of @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and @Celdor. I conducted additional research on the longtblr theme. Here is a sample of using the "longtblr" theme to align the table's caption to the left. Table 2 used a theme to align the caption to the left, and Table 3 without the theme caption will be center as default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

% A long table theme with table captions aligned to the left with some modifications.
\NewTblrTheme{longtable1}{
    \DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{fancy}{ [Continued]}
        \SetTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{fancy}

    \DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{fancy}{[Continue on next page]}
        \SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{fancy}

    \DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}{
        \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}
        \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}
        \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}
        }
    \DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{
        \UseTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}
        \UseTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}
        \UseTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}
        \UseTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}
        }}

\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{This is a normal table caption}
\begin{tblr}{
    width=1\linewidth,
    colspec={XXX},
    hlines, vlines
    }
Head & Head & Head \\
Head & Data & Data \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{longtblr}[
    theme=longtable1,
    caption={This is a long table that uses the ``longtblr'' theme to align the table's caption to the left}
    ]{
    width=1\linewidth,
    colspec={XXX},
    hlines, vlines,
    rowhead=1
    }
Head & Head & Head \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
\end{longtblr}

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption={This is a long table without a ``longtblr'' theme.}
    ]{
    width=1\linewidth,
    colspec={XXX},
    hlines, vlines,
    rowhead=1
    }
Head & Head & Head \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
Head & Data & Data \\ Head & Data & Data \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's looking all right. One thing though. Your example produces captions with extra spacing. Note my suggestion contains `%` at the end but not everywhere. If you enter a new line, LaTeX adds extra space and `%` prevents from it. Essentially the line: `A[ENTER]B[ENTER]C` is equivalent to "A B C" while `A%[ENTER]B[ENTER]C` is equivalent to `AB C`